# Proof of : $x^{n}\equiv x^{\varphi(m)+[n \bmod \varphi(m)]} \mod m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, totient-function

There is a lesser known generalization of Euler's Theorem. Here 'x' and 'm' are NOT COPRIME and $\,n\ge \log_2 m.\,$ I stumbled upon this on this site : http://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/phi-function.html 
The "derivation" can be found towards the end of the above link; but i can't seem to wrap my head around it. It would be really great if it could be explained a bit better, probably with an example.

Comment: Do you already know how to prove Euler's theorem?

Comment: Yes, I kind of understood it. But i didn't understand it from wikipedia. I went through some other resource which was able to generalize from Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Problem is here, 'x' and 'm' aren't coprime.. x and m can be any number. and 'n' >= log2(m)

Comment: Could you please go through the link I have added. What you are talking about is different from what I am looking for.

Comment: It would be easier to explain what you don't understand about the proof. It's pretty clear to me

Comment: In the derivation, an intermediate result : $x^n \bmod m = x^k\left(x^{n-k \bmod \phi(\frac{m}{a})} \bmod \frac{m}{a}\right)\bmod m$ is reached. Till that i understood, after that when the discussion about 'cycle' length started, i couldn't  understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a special case of  following generalization of the Euler-Fermat theorem. Indeed, let $\phi = \phi(m).\,$ By division we can write $\, n = q\,\phi + r,\,$ for $\,r = n\bmod \phi.\,$ Then the claim is that $$\bmod m\!:\,\ a^{\large q\,\phi+r}\equiv a^{\phi + r}\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ \ a^{\phi+r}(a^{(q-1)\phi}-1)\equiv 0,\ \ {\rm for\ all}\,\ a\in\Bbb Z\qquad$$

By the Theorem below this is true if $\,e := \phi + r\,$ is as least as large as the largest exponent in the prime factorization of $m$. The point is that we need to choose $\,e\,$ large enough so that the factor $\,a^e\,$ is divisible by all $\, p^{\large e_i}\,$ when $\,p\mid a,\,$ since then its cofactor $\,a^f-1\,$ is *not* divisible by $p.$

**Theorem** $\  $ Suppose that $\ m\in \mathbb N\ $ has the prime factorization $\:m = p_1^{e_{\:1}}\cdots\:p_k^{e_k}\ $ and suppose that for all $\,i,\,$  $\ e\ge e_i\ $ and $\ \phi(p_i^{e_{\:i}})\mid f.\ $ Then $\ m\mid a^e\,(a^f-1)\ $ for all $\: a\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof** $\ $ Notice that if $\ p_i\mid a\ $ then $\:p_i^{e_{\:i}}\ |\ a^e\ $ by $\ e_i \le e.\: $ Else $\:a\:$ is coprime to $\: p_i\:$ so by Euler's phi theorem, $\!\bmod q = p_i^{e_{\:i}}\!:\, \ a^{\phi(q)}\equiv 1 \Rightarrow\ a^f\equiv 1\, $ by $\: \phi(q)\mid f.\ $  Since all $\ p_i^{e_{\:i}}\ |\  a^e\ (a^f - 1)\ $ so too does their lcm = product = $m$.

**Remark** $\ $ You can find many illuminating examples in prior questions, e.g. below

[$24\mid a^3(a^2-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2408201/242)

[$40\mid a^3(a^4-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637468/242)

[$88\mid a^5(a^{20}-1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1316052/242)

[$6p\mid a\,b^p - b\,a^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003925/242)

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot for the response. Can you suggest some good resources to learn Group Theory. I feel like Group theory is a powerful tool to have. I see it pretty much in all number theory proofs. (Your proof didn't need any of it. My request is in general)

Comment: @Aizen Glad it helped. It's difficult if not impossible to make such recommendations without knowing *much* more about your background. To start I'd suggest browsing abstract algebra textbooks to find one at your level (and search the web to find recommendations for reputable textbooks since some are very poorly written).

Comment: @Aizen Can I just say, if you look online you may find the reccomandation for Dummit and Foote. In my opinion as a student, that is the worst math book I have ever seen. Just general, for abstract algebra books, I would reccomend Herstein (he has two books, one for undergrads and one for grads), Joseph Gallian, Fraleigh.

Comment: @Ovi Thanks a lot for your valuable feedback. Yes, I did encounter a bunch of recommendations for Dummit and Foote, as well as Herstein. I will look into both and see which one appeals me more. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=ab$ with $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(x,b)=1$.
Then
$$x^{\varphi (b)} \equiv 1\pmod b$$
If $a\mid x^k $, then
$$x^k x^{\varphi (b)} \equiv x^k\pmod {m}$$
This means that for $n\geq k$ the sequence $n\to x^n\bmod m$ is periodic with period $\varphi(b)$.

Since $\varphi (m)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b) $, we have, in particular, 
$$x^k x^{\varphi (m)} \equiv x^k\pmod {m}$$
hence for $n\geq k$ the sequence $n\to x^n\bmod m$ is also periodic with period $\varphi(m)$.

Since $a\mid x^{\varphi (m)} $, we can choose $k=\varphi(m)$, thus obtaining:
$$x^{2\varphi (m)} \equiv x^{\varphi (m)}\pmod {m}$$
which says that for $n\geq\varphi(m)$ the sequence $n\to x^n\bmod m$ is periodic with period $\varphi(m)$.

Consequently, for $n=q\varphi(m)+r$ with $r=n\bmod\varphi(m)$ and $q\geq 1$ we have
\begin{align}
x^n
&=x^{q\varphi(m)}x^r\\
&\equiv x^{\varphi(m)}x^r\pmod m\\
&\equiv x^{\varphi(m)+r}
\end{align}
because $x^{q\varphi(m)}\equiv x^{\varphi(m)}\pmod m$, which proves the assertion.

Comment: I simply am dumb enough to get the "periodic" part. I got lost in that line itself. Can you please elaborate on that, probably with some example.