# Euler's theorem modification?

Tags: totient-function

Let $a,b,n$ be any integers greater than $1$ and $b >\phi(n),$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function; is the below equation is true or not?
$$ a^b \equiv_n a^{\phi(n) + (b \mod \phi(n))}$$

Comment: To clarify, you are interested in the general situation where $\gcd(a,n)$ might not equal $1$?

Comment: If gcd($a,n)=1$ then $a^{\phi(n)}\equiv_n1$

Comment: @greg-martin, yes I'm interested in the general situation even more than square free generalization.

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof of : $x^{n}\equiv x^{\varphi(m)+[n \bmod \varphi(m)]} \mod m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938238/proof-of-xn-equiv-x-varphimn-bmod-varphim-mod-m)

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you.